Prediction model for dataset whose variables are on two different levels (patient- and lesion-level)
I want to create a cox regression model for predicting follow-up outcomes (eg death) using my dataset.
The issue is that my dataset has some variables that are patient-level (eg demographics) and some variables that are lesion-level (eg lesion characteristics).
The problem with that is that some patients have more than one lesions.
The way the dataset is formatted is that for second lesions in the same patient, the patient-level variables are missing so that they are not counted twice.
However, when I am trying to make a model that takes into account both patient- and lesion-level predictors I run into the issue of how I should deal with the 2nd lesion cases.
If I leave them as is, then the 2nd lesions are not taken into account, as the patient-level characteristics are missing and they are deleted from the model.
If I copy the patient-level characteristic from the first lesion, I end up using the same patient characteristics twice.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

I don't think there is an easy way to do this. I don't have time for a full answer right now, but one way of solving it would be to figure out some way to combine the lesion data. The best way to do this, if it's possible at all, would need substantive knowledge.
